# How to calculate total network traffic for a period of time for a specific application?

Tags: windows, networking, traffic

I'm doing performance testing of a native application on Windows and I need to calculate how much more internet traffic new application version produce compared to previous version. Because application is meant to be working in environment with limited internet connection.

[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) displays only HTTP and FTP requests and only those that were sent through proxy. In theory application can ignore proxy and use other protocols or sockets.

[Resource Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Monitor) seems to contains only average network activity for last minute (Total B/sec). It is not enough for me because network traffic produced by application is not constant.

[Network-related performance counters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574079(v=ws.11).aspx) doesn't contain no relevant counters to look at.

[TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx) for some reason do not show information for some processes. It display traffic for specific connection rather than application and when connection is closed information is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more detailed research I found that [Sysinternals Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) looks like appropriate tool for internet traffic estimation. You can add Network Send Bytes and Network Recieve Bytes columns to processes table and manually calculate their values difference at the time range boundaries that you are interested in. In order to this to work you need to start Process Explorer as administrator.